# Using ggplot2 to create a Histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

Still working in my project with R.

Here's the code I have so far.

```
# change columns to factors#
dat[, 9:23] <- lapply(dat[, 9:23], factor, levels = c(1, 2, 3, 4), labels = c("Nunca", 
                                                                            "1 vez por semana", "3 veces o menos a la semana", "Más de 4 veces a la semana"))
dat$Who_answers <- factor(dat$Who_answers, levels = c(1, 2, 3, 4), labels = c("Mamá", 
                                                                            "Papá", "Tutor", "Otro"))
dat$gender <- factor(dat$gender, levels = c(1, 2), labels = c("F", "M"))
dat$diagnosis <- factor(dat$diagnosis, levels = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), labels = c("Leucemia linfoblástica aguda", 
                                                                                 "Leucemia mieloide aguda", "Linfoma de Hodgkin", "Linfoma no Hodgkin", "Tumor del sistema nervioso central", "Tumor sólido", "Otro"))
dat$acomp_rutsu <- factor(dat$acomp_rutsu, levels = c(1, 2, 3, 4), labels = c("Mamá", "Papá", "Abuela(o)", "Otro tutor"))
dat$Duerme_con <- factor(dat$Duerme_con, levels = c(1, 2, 3, 4), labels = c("Padres", "Hermanos", "Abuelos", "Solo"))
dat$Cuarto_propio <- factor(dat$Cuarto_propio, levels = c(1, 2), labels = c("Sí", "No"))
dat$Hospitalizado <- factor(dat$Hospitalizado, levels = c(1, 2), labels = c("Sí", "No"))
dat$Min_dormir <- factor(dat$Min_dormir, levels = c(1, 2, 3, 4), labels = c("Menos de 5 minutos", 
                                                                          "Entre 5-10 minutos", "Entre 10-15 minutos", "Más de 15 minutos"))
dat$Max_dormir <- factor(dat$Max_dormir, levels = c(1, 2, 3, 4), labels = c("Entre 5-10 minutos", 
                                                                          "Entre 10-15 minutos", "Entre 15-30 minutos", "Más de 30 minutos"))
dat$Levanta_noche <- factor(dat$Levanta_noche, levels = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), labels = c("Nunca", 
                                                                                   "1 vez por noche", "2-3 veces por noche", "4-5 veces por noche", "Más de 5 veces por noche"))
dat$Tiempo_despNoche <- factor(dat$Tiempo_despNoche, levels = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), labels = c("No se despierta en las noches", 
                                                                                            "Menos de 30 minutos", "De 30-60 minutos", "De 1-2 horas", "De 2-4 horas", "Más de 5 horas"))
dat$Problema_dormirNoche <- factor(dat$Problema_dormirNoche, levels = c(1, 2, 3), labels = c("No se despierta en las noches", "Sí", "No"))
dat$Tan_descansado <- factor(dat$Tan_descansado, levels = c(1, 2, 3, 4), labels = c("Nada descansado", 
                                                                                  "Poco descansado", "Algo descansado", "Muy descansado"))
dat[, 31:36] <- lapply(dat[, 31:36], factor, levels = c(1, 2, 3, 4), labels = c("Nunca", 
                                                                              "1 vez por semana", "3 veces o menos a la semana", "Más de 4 veces a la semana"))
dat$Horas_duermeDia <- factor(dat$Horas_duermeDia, levels = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), labels = c("No duerme durante el día", 
                                                                                       "Menos de 1 hora", "De 1-2 horas", "De 2-4 horas", "5 o más horas"))

BD <- as.data.frame(dat)
str(BD)

#DESCRIPTIVE STATISTICS FOR FI#

#Frequency distribution FI
FI1_table <- table(BD$Who_answers, exclude=NULL)
FI2_table <- table(BD$age, exclude=NULL)
FI3_table <- table(BD$gender, exclude=NULL)
FI4_table <- table(BD$diagnosis, exclude=NULL)

FI1_table
FI2_table
FI3_table
FI4_table

prop.table(FI1_table)
prop.table(FI2_table)
prop.table(FI3_table)
prop.table(FI4_table)

gender_diagnosis <- table(BD$gender, BD$diagnosis) #Falta agregar más correlaciones interesantes
rownames(gender_diagnosis) <- c("Mujer", "Hombre")
gender_diagnosis
prop.table(gender_diagnosis)

age_diagnosis <- table (BD$age, BD$diagnosis)
age_diagnosis
prop.table(age_diagnosis)

#Central tendency FI
CT_FI <- import("Respuestas Prueba piloto para R 4.xlsx") %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  dplyr::select(1:4) %>%
  print()
stat.desc(CT_FI, norm = TRUE)

#Descriptive statistics in graphs FI
#Q1
HistoFI1 <-ggplot(BD,aes(Who_answers)) #Crear Histograma para variable única
HistoFI1 + geom_histogram(binwidth=0.4) + labs(x="Quién responde este cuestionario", y="Frecuencia", fill="SexL")
```

I have trouble generating this last ggplot. R shows me:

```
Error in `geom_histogram()`:
! Problem while computing stat.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `setup_params()`:
! `stat_bin()` requires a continuous x aesthetic
✖ the x aesthetic is discrete.
ℹ Perhaps you want `stat="count"`?
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
> rlang::last_error()
<error/rlang_error>
Error in `geom_histogram()`:
! Problem while computing stat.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `setup_params()`:
! `stat_bin()` requires a continuous x aesthetic
✖ the x aesthetic is discrete.
ℹ Perhaps you want `stat="count"`?
---
Backtrace:
  1. base (local) `<fn>`(x)
  2. ggplot2:::print.ggplot(x)
  4. ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
  5. ggplot2:::by_layer(...)
 12. ggplot2 (local) f(l = layers[[i]], d = data[[i]])
 13. l$compute_statistic(d, layout)
 14. ggplot2 (local) compute_statistic(..., self = self)
 15. self$stat$setup_params(data, self$stat_params)
 16. ggplot2 (local) setup_params(..., self = self)
```

Also, I tried this code:

```
ggplot(BD,aes(Who_answers))+
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), binwidth=0.4, color = "#000000", fill = "#0099F8") +
  geom_density(color = "#000000", fill = "#F85700", alpha = 0.6) +
  labs(x="Quién responde este cuestionario", y="Frecuencia", fill="SexL")
```

But R shows me this:

```
Error in `geom_histogram()`:
! Problem while computing stat.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `setup_params()`:
! `stat_bin()` requires a continuous x aesthetic
✖ the x aesthetic is discrete.
ℹ Perhaps you want `stat="count"`?
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
> rlang::last_error()
<error/rlang_error>
Error in `geom_histogram()`:
! Problem while computing stat.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `setup_params()`:
! `stat_bin()` requires a continuous x aesthetic
✖ the x aesthetic is discrete.
ℹ Perhaps you want `stat="count"`?
---
Backtrace:
  1. base (local) `<fn>`(x)
  2. ggplot2:::print.ggplot(x)
  4. ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
  5. ggplot2:::by_layer(...)
 12. ggplot2 (local) f(l = layers[[i]], d = data[[i]])
 13. l$compute_statistic(d, layout)
 14. ggplot2 (local) compute_statistic(..., self = self)
 15. self$stat$setup_params(data, self$stat_params)
 16. ggplot2 (local) setup_params(..., self = self)
```

I am relatively new to R and its language.
Is there any way you could help me understand the error and help me fix it?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: As the error says: "stat_bin() requires a continuous x aesthetic" but "the x aesthetic is discrete". In other words the x-value, `Who_answers`, should be a numeric variable, but you have set it to be a factor, which is a categorical (discrete) variable. Also it would help if your example were more minimal, with just the data and code required to illustrate the problem.